# can codeigniter calendar be styled in 2 different colors?

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I need to style a codeigniter calendar using the template provided in the user guide but I need that from day 1 to 15 from a given month be background-color red and from day 16 to the last day of the month to be blue.

Please someone help me with this. I am very grateful for everyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Creating a Calendar Template** 
here:
http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/calendar.html

or you can also use the **CSS3 :nth-child() Selector**

example:

```
p:nth-child(2) {
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

in the example above you specify a background color for every `<p>` element that is the second child of its `parent:`